# conditional average using dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working with a cross-country panel dataset.

I want to create a new variable (let's call it `C1`) such that the variable for Argentina in 1999 reflects the average value of inf from the beginning of the sample till the previous year (i.e., 1998).

Likewise, C1 for Turkey in 1991 reflects the average of inf from the beginning of the sample till 1990. Note that the first year for which data is available might be different for each country.

I would like to ideally do this using `dplyr`. Any suggestions or leads would be much appreciated.

Below is a snapshot of my data.

```r
# A tibble: 82 x 3
   country    year   inf
   <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Argentina  1960 NA   
 2 Argentina  1961 20.3 
 3 Argentina  1962 28.9 
 4 Argentina  1963 25.6 
 5 Argentina  1964 28.8 
 6 Argentina  1965 21.2 
 7 Argentina  1966 25.6 
 8 Argentina  1967 29.0 
 9 Argentina  1968 10.3 
10 Argentina  1969  7.80
# ... with 72 more rows
```

---

```
structure(list(country = c("Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
"Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
"Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
"Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
"Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
"Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
"Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
"Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", 
"Argentina", "Argentina", "Argentina", "Turkey", "Turkey", "Turkey", 
"Turkey", "Turkey", "Turkey", "Turkey", "Turkey", "Turkey", "Turkey", 
"Turkey", "Turkey", "Turkey", "Turkey", "Turkey", "Turkey", "Turkey", 
"Turkey", "Turkey", "Turkey", "Turkey", "Turkey", "Turkey", "Turkey", 
"Turkey", "Turkey", "Turkey", "Turkey", "Turkey", "Turkey", "Turkey", 
"Turkey", "Turkey", "Turkey", "Turkey", "Turkey", "Turkey", "Turkey", 
"Turkey", "Turkey", "Turkey"), year = c(1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, 
1964, 1965, 1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 
1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 
1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 
1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 
1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 
1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 
1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 
2000), inf = c(NA, 20.3106975252928, 28.8718416517331, 25.5911543481732, 
28.7746173195633, 21.2329349235212, 25.6034624263967, 29.0182629356081, 
10.2753105574405, 7.79583003660558, 6.46787463937974, 31.2710638825753, 
64.2447859181755, 65.5352873661713, 30.6304413715773, 197.697364540376, 
438.322779724218, 159.427177705708, 161.372172005774, 147.377044038694, 
95.7904246111226, 105.27636637456, 194.535299671424, 380.158528520508, 
611.196303889043, 607.447497820506, 77.2922366864323, 127.539918062845, 
381.246344411434, 3046.09115199662, 2078.31681803114, 140.502378663632, 
16.0719935356945, -3.56109557576575, 2.84933971509302, 3.16512339016516, 
-0.0523754965904146, -0.46391313116429, -1.70527962400085, -1.83655839220664, 
1.03728710073175, NA, 4.37340043959567, 5.78893779037435, 6.4166944802911, 
2.35243651899155, 4.11785566096488, 5.94759067350768, 5.93989052660011, 
4.76015624386707, 6.87631710287759, 8.64450444669336, 16.9020871544943, 
10.9756760490106, 21.9302187016976, 28.9923473546045, 21.3092400682888, 
15.6126574914859, 24.0890232450352, 47.5411467102416, 76.7208667189401, 
93.0032247916414, 44.0570704966979, 28.2268344007077, 26.2582454161426, 
48.2368326072076, 53.054476874505, 36.0068855504432, 33.6122290331458, 
69.0181311101417, 75.4048306122696, 58.2443981066746, 59.1641068909336, 
65.1994382769795, 68.3794283559812, 104.749137215122, 86.007542441817, 
77.223512216706, 81.4548625820616, 143.639661614673, 54.2799583040521, 
49.3607762430324)), row.names = c(NA, -82L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cummean`. Since you're first value is NA, you can `group_by` NA values and country, and apply the `cummean`.

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(country, na = is.na(inf)) %>% 
  mutate(C1 = head(c(NA, cummean(inf)), -1)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-na)

# A tibble: 82 x 4
   country    year   inf    C1
   <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Argentina  1960 NA     NA  
 2 Argentina  1961 20.3   NA  
 3 Argentina  1962 28.9   20.3
 4 Argentina  1963 25.6   24.6
 5 Argentina  1964 28.8   24.9
 6 Argentina  1965 21.2   25.9
 7 Argentina  1966 25.6   25.0
 8 Argentina  1967 29.0   25.1
 9 Argentina  1968 10.3   25.6
10 Argentina  1969  7.80  23.7
# ... with 72 more rows
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but this did not work.

Comment: It started working after the edit you have made. This is very neat! thank you!

Comment: @Mael I am very interested in how in this code ```mutate(C1 = head(c(NA, cummean(inf)), -1))``` this section of it works: ```C1 = head(c(NA, cummean(inf)), -1)```. If to get an answer to this I need to start a new post, I will be glad to do that.

Comment: @Metsfan It's a bit of a hacky solution. Basically, `head(x, -1)` removes the last element, and `c(NA, x)` adds an NA in the beginning. This is to mimic a lagged variable.

Answer (score 1):

To deal with the years with missing values, you can compute the running mean in another dataframe with missings dropped, then merge the results back into your original dataframe.

```r
library(dplyr)

avg_calc <- mydata %>% 
  filter(!is.na(inf)) %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  mutate(
    C1 = cummean(inf),
    year = year + 1,    # add one to year so merged avg reflects previous year
    inf = NULL
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()

mydata <- mydata %>% 
  left_join(avg_calc)

mydata
#> # A tibble: 82 x 4
#>    country    year   inf    C1
#>    <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 Argentina  1960 NA     NA  
#>  2 Argentina  1961 20.3   NA  
#>  3 Argentina  1962 28.9   20.3
#>  4 Argentina  1963 25.6   24.6
#>  5 Argentina  1964 28.8   24.9
#>  6 Argentina  1965 21.2   25.9
#>  7 Argentina  1966 25.6   25.0
#>  8 Argentina  1967 29.0   25.1
#>  9 Argentina  1968 10.3   25.6
#> 10 Argentina  1969  7.80  23.7
#> # ... with 72 more rows
```